# Combine results from two conditional aggregation queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My issue is how to combine the results into a single result set.

The first query is as follows

```
Select StampId,Country,
    max(case when seqnum = 1 then color end) as "color 1",
    max(case when seqnum = 2 then color end) as "color 2",
    max(case when seqnum = 3 then color end) as "color 3",
    max(case when seqnum = 4 then color end) as "color 4"
    from (select StampTable.StampId,[CountryTable].Country,ColorKeyTable.Color,row_number() over (partition by StampTable.Stampid order by ColorKeyTable.colorkeyid) as seqnum
    from StampTable 
    left join StampColorKeyTable on StampColorKeyTable.stampid = StampTable.stampid
    left Join CountryTable on StampTable.Country = CountryTable.CountryId
    left join colorKeyTable on StampColorKeyTable.colorkeyid = ColorKeyTable.ColorKeyId
    ) StampColorKeyTable
    group by stampId,Country
```

The typical results for this are

[image]

My next query is

```
SELECT s.StampId 
   , ct.Country
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 1 and q.MintUsedId = 1 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as HaveMNH
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 1 and q.MintUsedId = 2 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as HaveMH 
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 1 and q.MintUsedId = 3 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as HaveUsed
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 2 and q.MintUsedId = 1 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as WantMNH
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 2 and q.MintUsedId = 2 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as WantMH 
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 2 and q.MintUsedId = 3 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as WantUsed
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 3 and q.MintUsedId = 1 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as TradeMNH
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 3 and q.MintUsedId = 2 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as TradeMH 
   , MAX(case when q.statusId = 3 and q.MintUsedId = 3 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as TradeUsed
FROM StampTable s
LEFT JOIN StampQuantatiesTable sq ON s.StampId = sq.StampId
LEFT JOIN QuantatiesTable q ON q.QuantatiesId = sq.QuantatiesId
left Join CountryTable ct on S.Country = ct.CountryId
GROUP BY s.StampId 
       , ct.Country
```

The typical results for this are

[image]

Please note that either one of these expressions has far more left joins to return for more data but for expediency they have been omitted from these queries.

The combined results I am looking to achieve are

[image]

Any assistance would be much appreciated as I have been unable to find very little information on this from my searches.

Comment: Just a note: if you group by certain columns, the rows will already be distinct. No need the `SELECT DISTINCT` in that case. Also, you can just both resultsets, e.g. by populating them in CTEs or materialize the results in a table variable or temporary table.

Comment: Thank you for that, unsure how that crept into the code other than my experiments on how to resolve my problem. I have removed it from the expression.

Comment: Are both queries guaranteed to return the same number of rows? If not how should the join take place? Regardless it seems you want to join both queries together, which you can easily do either using CTEs, sub-queries or temp tables.

Comment: Points to note, 1) Please don't add tag names to the title (e.g. SQL Server etc). 2) Please stop using images to display data. Instead use formatted text. 3. Please start to provide sample data, either as formatted text, but ideally as DDL/DML so people can copy and paste it out for testing.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and my apologies if i have not followed the correct procedure for posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a `JOIN` of the two queries. In short,

```sql
SELECT * FROM (query1) t1
JOIN (query2) t2
ON t1.stampId = t2.stampId AND t1.Country = t2.Country
```

The full query can look like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    Select StampId,Country,
        max(case when seqnum = 1 then color end) as "color 1",
        max(case when seqnum = 2 then color end) as "color 2",
        max(case when seqnum = 3 then color end) as "color 3",
        max(case when seqnum = 4 then color end) as "color 4"
        from (select StampTable.StampId,[CountryTable].Country,ColorKeyTable.Color,row_number() over (partition by StampTable.Stampid order by ColorKeyTable.colorkeyid) as seqnum
        from StampTable 
        left join StampColorKeyTable on StampColorKeyTable.stampid = StampTable.stampid
        left Join CountryTable on StampTable.Country = CountryTable.CountryId
        left join colorKeyTable on StampColorKeyTable.colorkeyid = ColorKeyTable.ColorKeyId
        ) StampColorKeyTable
        group by stampId,Country
) t1
JOIN (
    SELECT s.StampId 
       , ct.Country
       , MAX(case when q.statusId = 1 and q.MintUsedId = 1 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as HaveMNH
       , MAX(case when q.statusId = 1 and q.MintUsedId = 2 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as HaveMH 
       , MAX(case when q.statusId = 1 and q.MintUsedId = 3 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as HaveUsed
       , MAX(case when q.statusId = 2 and q.MintUsedId = 1 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as WantMNH
       , MAX(case when q.statusId = 2 and q.MintUsedId = 2 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as WantMH 
       , MAX(case when q.statusId = 2 and q.MintUsedId = 3 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as WantUsed
       , MAX(case when q.statusId = 3 and q.MintUsedId = 1 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as TradeMNH
       , MAX(case when q.statusId = 3 and q.MintUsedId = 2 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as TradeMH 
       , MAX(case when q.statusId = 3 and q.MintUsedId = 3 then 'True' ELSE 'False' END) as TradeUsed
    FROM StampTable s
    LEFT JOIN StampQuantatiesTable sq ON s.StampId = sq.StampId
    LEFT JOIN QuantatiesTable q ON q.QuantatiesId = sq.QuantatiesId
    left Join CountryTable ct on S.Country = ct.CountryId
    GROUP BY s.StampId 
           , ct.Country
) t2
ON t1.stampId = t2.stampId AND t1.Country = t2.Country
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. This works in combining the two queries but iI note that the StampId and Country are duplicated in the results. I assumed changing the Select * to naming the required columns would resolve this but I get an error "multi-part identifier could not be bound" for StampId and Country or Ambiguous Column name dependent upon how i name the Columns i.e StampTable.StampId or StampId. Any ideas?

Comment: Resolved the issue needed to utilise t1 or t2 prefix to stampId and Country i.e t1.StampId